# Displaying changeable number of images in a grid using C#/Xaml

Tags: c#, windows, image, xaml

I have a method that retrieves a list of absolute paths to images. I wish to use these retrieved values to display a grid of images inside of a Windows 8 application. The caveats being that the list can be of any size, and I wish for the images to fill the screen and continue downwards.

This seems like a really simple question, but I cannot find any definitive answer on how to do this using Google/Bing - so I said I would post it up here on the off chance that someone knows what to do in this case.

At the moment, I am simply retrieving a list of files from my music folder, and appending them to a string which is displayed on screen - no images appear, and I have no idea how I would make this work with a dynamic number of images. Can anybody help me with this ?

Code thus far :

Retrieves images in music folder :

```
 private async void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFolder musicFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;

            List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, fileTypeFilter);
            //use the user's input to make a query
            queryOptions.UserSearchFilter = InputTextBox.Text;
            StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = musicFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

            StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();

            //find all files that match the query
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
            //output how many files that match the query were found
            if (files.Count == 0)
            {
                outputText.Append("No files found for '" + queryOptions.UserSearchFilter + "'");
            }
            else if (files.Count == 1)
            {
                outputText.Append(files.Count + " file found:\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                outputText.Append(files.Count + " files found:\n\n");
            }

            //output the name of each file that matches the query
            foreach (StorageFile file in files)
            {
                outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");
            }

            OutputTextBlock.Text = outputText.ToString();
        }
```

And the XAML for OutputTextBlock which displays the file names, but no images :

```
<Grid x:Name="Output" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock x:Name="OutputTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this will work for a Windows 8 App... But in WPF, I'd try someting like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourListOfPaths}" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` is bound to your list of file paths (e.G. an `ObservableCollection<string>`), the `ItemTemplate` describes how each single item is displayed - I just used an `Image` control for each single file. The `Source` is bound to the item itself (this is a single file path here).